# Multithreading WPF Application Question

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application like this.

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
 /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
 /// </summary>
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
public delegate void NextPrimeDelegate();
int i = 0;

public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

 public void CheckNextNumber()
{
  i++;
  textBox1.Text= i.ToString();
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
      System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle,
      new NextPrimeDelegate(this.CheckNextNumber));

 }

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
      DispatcherPriority.Normal,
      new NextPrimeDelegate(CheckNextNumber));
  }
 }
```

Above code is working without problem.My question is:I want to call more than a function that is  called CheckNextNumber.
For example:I have to make something like this.

```
tr[0].Start();
tr[0].Stop();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C# version prior to 3.0 you can use anonymous delegates:

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (NextPrimeDelegate)delegate()
 { 
    tr[0].Start();
    tr[0].Stop(); 
 });
```

Beginning with C# 3.0 you can use lambdas (which is basically syntactic sugar on top of anonymous delegates). Additionally you don't need your `NextPrimeDelegate` because .NET 3.5 introduced the generic parameterless `Action` delegate.

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
 { 
    tr[0].Start();
    tr[0].Stop(); 
 });
```

Comment: @bitbonk-First of all,thanks for your interesting.I want to ask a question.How can I use parallel programming to call more than one function at a time by using Parallel Invoke?(for same application)

Comment: You should put that as a new separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a delegate, you can use an Action with a codeblock with whatever code you like, e.g:

```
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
      DispatcherPriority.Normal,
      new Action(() =>
      {
          tr[0].Start();
          tr[0].Stop();
      }));
```